# Does ESP32 can support WIFIDirect

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, wifi, wireless, esp32-cam

I would like to establish a simple P2P connection between an ESP32 and an Android device without the use of an access point. I should be able to send and receive data from the ESP32 through the established connection. Is this possible, and if not, are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research i for to know that we can't use wifi direct for esp32 i found an alternative for my problem!!!!

Comment: can you maybe share your alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

I do know that you can host a web page on an esp8266, sending and receiving data on that. You can from there connect the Android to that web page. I am not sure what you mean by access point, and I hope that this method is not using an access point.

Comment: Acccess point means router

Comment: so this approach should work?